# Some functions from library works in python shell but not in a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm having trouble getting certain functions from a library called art (https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/art) to run in a script, though they work fine in a shell. The script/commands entered sequentially look like this:

`from art import * 
 randart()           <(function fails in script, but succeeds in shell)
 tart("test")        <(different function, same library, succeeds in both shell and script)
 import sys
 print(sys.version)`

The python version is 3.7.5 for both the shell and the script. The first function does not throw an error when run in a script, but does not give any output. Its desired output is a random ascii_art from a collection. I feel like I'm missing something really simple. Any ideas? The documentation on github reports "Some environments don't support all 1-Line arts", however they are the same python version on the same machine. Are there other portions of the environment that could be the cause?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print `randart()` while writing in script. Make a habit of using `print()` for everything while printing. Shell is the place which returns the value by default whereas you need to tell the script window what to do with any name or function. 
so use this:

```
from art import * 
print(randart())
```

Answer (score 1):

in the shell it is implicitly printed ... in a script you must explicitly

```
print(randart())
```